# Rails console is not outputting SQL Statements to my Development Log

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, development-environment

When I access my Webrick server via the localhost, or when I run rails migrations, my development.log is correctly written to.  However, when I bootup my rails console with "rails c" and then try and create a new database object and save it via a command like "user.save", I see SQL statements in the console, but nothing is written to in the development log.

Most people when answering a question similar to this say "check to make sure that the config is set to the correct environment".  I've done this, and can say on my system this happens for a completely new rails app.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

the rails console never writes to the log file, but you can achieve it quite easily, for example, if you execute following after starting the rails console

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new STDOUT
```

rails will log all SQL statements to stdout, thus display them in your terminal.
and since `Logger.new` accepts any stream as first argument, you could just let it write to the rails development.log:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new File.open('log/development.log', 'a')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  You say Rails console never writes to the log file.  To me, this seems add odds to what Michael Hartl teaches in section 6.1.3 of "The Ruby on Rails Tutorial 3".. which says:   .. working at the console, it’s useful to keep an eye on the development log, which records the actual low-level SQL statements being issued by Active Record, as shown in Figure 6.4. The way to get this output at a Unix command line is to tail the log:

$ tail -f log/development.log - Am I to take it then that in this situation its Active Record that's writing to the log?  If so.. mine fails

Comment: i'm absolutely sure, that rails doesn't normally log to file in console mode. it would be quite embarrassing if I'm wrong :), but maybe i am? or maybe you missed some setup section in Hartl's book ? i didn't read that book, so i don't know.

Comment: to be exact, Rails' different parts, i.e. ActionController, ActiveRecord etc. all write to the log. you can set different loggers for these frameworks, or just set Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT), but in the rails console, you have not logging from controllers etc, as you usually only work with models

Comment: Confirmed with version 3.1.1: The Rails console does **not** log to development.log.

Comment: 3.2.x *does* add "Connecting to database specified by database.yml" to the development log, but SQL statements are sent to STDOUT.

Answer (score 34):

I am in Rails 2.3.8, the above answer doesn't really work for me.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new STDOUT
```

The following actually works:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_set :@logger, Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Reference http://www.shanison.com/2012/03/05/show-sql-statements-in-rails-console/